# ARM Cortex M4 tune rearranging an unsigned int variable

Tags: performance, arm, signal-processing, cortex-m

I'm just starting to learn the ARM cortex-M4, which have advanced functions like DSP instructions,......

```
uint32_t my_rearrange(uint32_t value){
   uint32_t value_high = (value & 0xffff0000)>>16;
   uint32_t value_low  = (value & 0x0000ffff);
   return (value_low<<16)|value_high;
}
```

This is a simple code for rearranging an unsigned int variable.
Is there anyway to tune this function for best performance or fastest execution in cortex-M4? Is there a way for me to use the dsp instructions in this function?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any of the dsp instructions for this. All you appear to be doing is a 16 bit rotate. The compiler should recognise this and generate a `ROR`. GCC 5.4.1 with flags `-O3 -std=c++11 -march=armv7-m -mtune=cortex-m4 -mthumb` does, and for your code [generates](https://godbolt.org/g/Yze64b)

```
my_rearrange(unsigned long):
    ror     r0, r0, #16
    bx      lr
```

The only way you could speed it up would be if it was inlined.